# Converting fstream to float

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm trying to read the file:

> A = 10
>
> B = 20.009
>
> C is 20.09, 30.09

My code to convert the float/ int values encountered is:

```
int main ()
{
fstream file1, file2;
string line;
int N;
float W;
file1.open("input.txt");
file2.open("output.txt");
if (file1)  
  {
   while (getline( file1, line ))  
  {
    if(line[0] == 'A')
    {
        file1 >> W;
        cout << "A ="<<W; 
    }   
    else if(line[0] == 'B')
    {
        file1 >> W;
        cout << W; 
    }
  }
  file1.close();
 }
 else cout << "Can't open file\n";

 return 0;
 }
```

But I end up getting W = 0 . Where am I going wrong? Do I have to use fscanf??

Comment: You're getting `W = 0` for both if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first call to getline, the file is now pointed at the newline between the A and B lines. When you try to extract the float, it won't see anything looking like a floating point value, it hits the newline and quits trying.

You need to parse each line you read into your line variable, or use operator>> to parse it directly from the file like you are trying to do with the floating point values.